# Missing keyword error in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

```
create view PUBLISHER_VC as
SELECT PB_NAME, PB_ZIPCODE, PB_PHONE_NUMBER
FROM PUBLISHER_4_14 pub
     INNER JOIN BOOKS_4_14 boo
where pub.PBID=boo.PBID and BK_LIST_PRICE>100;
```

I have two tables called `PUBLISHER_4_14` and `BOOKS_4_14`. Publisher has the `PB_NAME`, `PB_ZIPCODE`, and the `PB_PHONENUMBER` columns. `BOOKS_4_14` has `BK_LIST_PRICE`.

I'm trying to create a view with the name `PUBLISHER_VC` that includes name, zip code and phone number of publishers who have never published a book and whose list price is less than $100. When I run it I get a missing keyword error. I made sure I have the correct table and column names too.

Comment: Have you tried to execute just the query (i.e. without the `create view`-part)?

Answer (score 1):

You are using an `INNER JOIN`, you need to specify the join condition in the `ON` clause of the join rather than in the `WHERE` clause:

```
create view PUBLISHER_VC as
SELECT PB_NAME, PB_ZIPCODE, PB_PHONE_NUMBER
FROM PUBLISHER_4_14 pub
     INNER JOIN BOOKS_4_14 boo
     ON ( pub.PBID=boo.PBID)
where BK_LIST_PRICE>100;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create a view with the name PUBLISHER_VC that includes
>   name, zip code and phone number of publishers who has never published
>   a book whose list price is less than $100.

That is not what your query does.  Here is a working version:

```
create view PUBLISHER_VC as
    SELECT PB_NAME, PB_ZIPCODE, PB_PHONE_NUMBER
    FROM PUBLISHER_4_14 pub
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT
                      FROM BOOKS_4_14 boo
                      WHERE pub.PBID = boo.PBID and boo.BK_LIST_PRICE <= 100
                     );
```